# "I did not see him yesterday" vs. "I had not seen him yesterday"

Tags: usage, past-tense

> (1) I did not see him yesterday.
>
> (2) I had not seen him yesterday.

Do they both mean exactly the same thing? Should (1) be chosen (as it almost always is, except for third conditionals) because it is simpler, in a sense?

**EDIT:** what I think the sentences mean is "at no point in time in yesterday did I see him". Am I wrong?

Comment: http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/pastperfect.html

Comment: This cannot be answered without more context. What comes before and after this sentence?

Comment: @StoneyB, so you're saying that on their own they mean different things?

Comment: We use the simple past to talk about something that happened before now; we use the past perfect when we are talking about the past and need to mention something that happened before the past time we are talking about.

Comment: your edited version is not exactly right. Because there is no emphasis on 'at no point' - as you have suggested in your sentence

Comment: They don't mean the same. The difference is the same difference between the simple present and the present perfect.

Answer (score 2):

Difference between use of simple past and past perfect depends on the context, e.g.

*Simple Past:* In reply to "Did you see your friend, whom you usually see every day, yesterday?" you might reply "I did not see him yesterday."

*Past Perfect:* In reply to "When did you notice your friend missing?" you might reply "I had not seen him yesterday."